# Need help fixing broken relational links in MySQL database after an upgrade

Tags: mysql

I have recently upgraded a forum database but the posts are not linking to the users.  Looking at the tables, I can see the following (example with all tables shortened for brevity):

jos_posts:

```
 Poster = Guest  (which is incorrect)
 Poster_ID = 0   (which is incorrect)
 Topic_ID = 10
```

jos_Topics:

```
 id = 10
 Poster = Ian
```

jos_users:

```
 Poster_ID = 2153
 Username = Ian
```

So although the poster_ID  is incorrectly showing 0 in jos_posts, the relational link to the Topic_ID means that the real Poster and, subsequently the Poster_ID from the jos_users table, can be found and, hopefully, the jos_posts table updated.

It seems to me that I would need to carry out the following steps:

1. look at each post in jos_posts, save the Topic_ID to a variable,
2. Go to the jos_topics table and search for the id, and save the Poster to a variable,
3. Go to jos_users, and serach for the Poster and save the Poster_ID to a variable,
4. Go back to the jos_posts and update the Poster and Poster_ID with the variables collected.
5. Finally skip down a row, and loop the above until there are no more records in the jos_posts table.

Now to my question:  My php/SQL coding is very poor, so can anyone confirm my logic above is correct and, if possible, point me in the right direction to write a short program that can correct the jos_posts table?

Comment: Is Poster_ID resolving as 0 every time?  That could be critical -- could mean a variable is not being looked up and defaults to 0.  So maybe a small fix and you're good.

Comment: If your analysis of the problem is correct, someone will shortly provide you with an update query that fixes everything upon running.

Answer (score 1):

No need for looping, it's just two simple SQL statements:

```
update jos_posts set poster_id = (
  select u.poster_id from jos_topics t, jos_users u 
  where t.id = topic_id and t.poster = u.username);
```

With a subsequent update of the poster column, everything should be fine:

```
update jos_posts set poster = (
 select u.username from jos_users u where u.poster_id = poster_id);
```

Comment: I can't validate the SQL fully, but this looks about right.  Xaade's comment about redundancy may be important too.

Comment: Xaade is right - redundancy in a RDBMS is nearly always caused by bad design.

Comment: Yes ... it is rarely caused by good design ... many say "never" rather than "rarely".

Comment: Sometimes, in a DWH environment, it makes sense to denormalize the data for performance purposes - but that's rarely necessary.

Comment: Beware: the 2nd SQL statement contains a bug - you should use the corrected version suggested by @Ekkehard Homer

Answer (score 0):

It would probably do you better to just grab all the records in jos_posts and iterate through them, performing the other operations you listed.

```
$posts = mysql_query("select * from jos_posts");
if($posts){
  while($post = mysql_fetch_array($posts)){
     $topic = $post['Topic_ID'];
     /* Look up the topic and get poster */
     /* Look up the user and get the id */
     $sql = "UPDATE jos_posts SET Poster = '".$poster
           ."', Poster_ID = '."$posterid"
           .' WHERE Topic_ID = '".$topic."'";
     mysql_query($sql);
  }
}
```

Something like that might work out...adding logic as necessary.

Comment: Hi Justin,  I used the suggestion from Xaade and created the SELECT statement, which worked perfectly to get the Poster_ID, Topic_ID & Poster.  I then wanted to try your approach to use the results of teh SELECT in an array, as per your suggestion.  Below is the code I wrote, but no update takes place??  I am guessing that I am not grabbing the records correectly in $post??  Any ideas (and thanks in advance)?

Comment: $posts = mysql_query("SELECT jos_agora_topics.ID AS topic_id, jos_agora_topics.Poster as poster, jos_agora_users.ID as poster_id
FROM jos_agora_topics INNER JOIN jos_agora_users ON jos_agora_topics.Poster = jos_agora_users.Username"); 

echo $posts["topic_id"]; 

if($posts){   

while($post = mysql_fetch_array($posts)){      
$topic = $post['topic_id'];$poster = $post['poster'];$posterid = $post['poster_id'];
/* Update Posts Table */
$sql = "
 UPDATE jos_agora_posts 
 SET Poster = '$poster', Poster_ID = '$posterid' 
 WHERE ID = '$topic'";      
mysql_query($sql);   
    } 
}

Comment: If you look at the while loop in the answer I posted, it should demonstrate how to iterate through the record set returned by mysql_query() function. You have to fetch each row individually (hence why you use the loop).

Comment: Hi Justin,  I tried this but it did not update anything???         if($posts){ while($post = mysql_fetch_array($posts)){ $topic = $post['topic_id']; $poster = $post['poster']; $posterid = $post['poster_id']; /* Update Posts Table */ $sql = " UPDATE jos_agora_posts SET Poster = '$poster', Poster_ID = '$posterid' WHERE ID = '$topic'"; mysql_query($sql); } }   I am obviously missing something but can't figure it out?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Justin...  I worked it out.  Thank you and to everyone else for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to select all users and their ids.

SELECT jos_Topics.Topic_ID, jos_Topics.Poster, jos_users.Poster_ID
FROM jos_Topics
INNER JOIN jos_users
ON jos_Topics.Poster=jos_users.Username

Update jos_posts Poster_ID using the previous query.

However, I'm pretty sure your problem is that you have the data in two places to begin with. The whole point of relational databases is to eliminate redundancies.

Comment: This select statement works perfectly: SELECT jos_agora_topics.ID AS Topic_ID, jos_agora_topics.Poster, jos_agora_users.ID AS Poster_ID FROM jos_agora_topics INNER JOIN jos_agora_users ON jos_agora_topics.Poster = jos_agora_users.Username     so now I am working on the update.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely off topic, I hope:

Ian surely did a good job to describe his problem. However, with a little bit of further work, the description could be augmented with a script that makes the problem testable:

```
use test;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jos_posts;

CREATE TABLE jos_posts (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  , Poster VARCHAR( 20 )
  , Poster_ID INTEGER
  , Topic_ID INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO jos_posts VALUES (1, 'GUEST', 0, 10);
INSERT INTO jos_posts VALUES (2, 'GUEST', 0, 20);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jos_topics;

CREATE TABLE jos_topics (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  , Poster VARCHAR( 20 )
);

INSERT INTO jos_topics VALUES (10, 'JAN');
INSERT INTO jos_topics VALUES (20, 'JON');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jos_users;

CREATE TABLE jos_users (
    Poster_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  , Username VARCHAR( 20 )
);

INSERT INTO jos_users VALUES (2153, 'JAN');
INSERT INTO jos_users VALUES (2154, 'JON');

SELECT * FROM jos_posts;

-- please insert solution here    

SELECT * FROM jos_posts;
```

Then a guru like Frank Schmitt could post his solution immediately and a nitpicker like me wouldn't need hours to get evidence for the objection that

```
update jos_posts set poster = (
  select u.username from jos_users u where u.poster_id = poster_id
);
```

should be:

```
update jos_posts p set poster = (
  select u.username from jos_users u where u.poster_id = p.poster_id
);
```

Comment: In fact, in my first draft I had it exactly like suggested by you (with the p alias), but I tested it in SQLite, and SQLite apparently doesn't accept an alias for the table that should be updated.  But you are right of course, the alias should definitely be used.

Comment: If your RDBMS is kind of brain dead and doesn't accept an alias for the updating table (like SQLite), you can also use the table name: update jos_posts set poster = (select u.username from jos_users u where u.poster_id = jos_posts.poster_id);